# PHP/MySql Undefined index for field name

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating my own blogging site. I cant seem to figure out whats wrong with this for 2 days. What I'm trying to do is get the author id from a table and then get author information from another table.

```
// Get post author
$post_id = $_GET["view"];
$post_row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT post_author FROM posts WHERE post_id='$post_id'"));
$post_author = $post_row["post_author"];

// Get post author information
$author_row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id='$post_author'"));
$author_username = $author_row["user_name"];
echo $author_username;
```

However, I'm getting this error message, Notice: Undefined index: user_name in... I'm sure I've spelled the field name right. There's nothing wrong with the first part of the code. How is the second part a problem? There exactly the same.

Comment: This is scary code! The errors from the sql function will disappear this way and your are vulnerable to several hacks (you just put the get variable in a query!) PLEASE, do not use this code in production!

Comment: Seriously! Read up on paramerterized queries (PDO) and SQL injection

Comment: +1 for using PDO, SQL injection could cause really big problems

Comment: You are not selecteting user_name from the table....

Answer (score 4):

You do

```
SELECT id
```

but then you look for the row `user_name`. It's not there, so you get the warning that the index isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting column `id` in your query, but then you are using `$author_row["user_name"]`.
change it to `$author_row["id"]` or use `SELECT user_name` in your query

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting only field `id` from the database. `user_name` is not there because you haven't selected it.

```
$author_row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id, user_name FROM users WHERE id='$post_author'"));
```

Debugging tip: Always do `print_r( $author_row )` to see what the query actually returns in cases like this. Not applicable in this case but equally important is to do `echo mysql_error()` to check that there wasn't an error in the query itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$author_row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$post_author'"));
```

use this query to get all information of the user.